# filter value if contain Array and join()

Tags: javascript

I want to check every `value` element inside an Array, check if it contain an Array or not.
If found, make all the element inside `value Array` to become string. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
this.array.filter( tgt => tgt.value).includes(Array()).join('++')
```

initial array

```
[{id: 1, value: [{true,false}]},{id: 2, value: "foo"}]
```

final array

```
[{id: 1, value: "true++false"},{id: 2, value: "foo"}]
```

Comment: `[{true,false}]` this is not valid. Do you mean `[true,false]` ?

Comment: yes, my bad. it should be```[true,false]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
const initial_array = [{ id: 1, value: [true, false] }, { id: 2, value: "foo" }]

function process(arr) {
    return arr.map(el => {
        return (Array.isArray(el.value)) ? { ...el, value: el.value.join('++') } : el
    })
}

console.log(process(initial_array))
```

basically we're mapping all the elements of the array individually. If `value` is an array then replace it using the code you provided, otherwise include it without change.
The `{...el, value: ___}` bit uses the spread operator to replace the `value` field of the object